# Strange output data when passing through two classes

Tags: c++, pointers, android-ndk, eigen

MY stattic llib have some unstable numeric results: so I just started looking for the  reason: and found some very strange output data with android_log in NDK c++ side.

This is my part of code where is log:

The data is input matrixd

```
SpectralClustering::SpectralClustering(Eigen::MatrixXd& data, int numDims)
    : mNumDims(numDims), mNumClusters(0)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd Deg;

    for ( int ijk2 = 0; ijk2 <data.rows(); ++ijk2) {
        double fde=data(ijk2,0);
        LOGD( "This is a number from JNI: %d", fde );
    }

    Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd> es(data,true);
}
```

The data have numbers between -1;1 (I check it its ok) but when i passing and create object with this class:

```
SpectralClustering* cls = new SpectralClustering(DATA, spec_vec4);
```

The output data is very strange its something about 16058451212.....

I guess the problem will be some¨where about and memory but when I deleting this its same.

Answer (score 1):

Well you do print the `double` as an `int`, so you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

You might want to use the proper floating point format `"%f"`. See e.g. [this `printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).